# using powershell, is it possible to convert an XLSX file to XLS?

Tags: powershell, xls, xlsx

As the title states, is this possible? I found some scripts for XLS to XLSX, but not the other way around.

Can this be done with powershell?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it can be done. If you can do it with a mouse you can do it in a script. Nothing is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup your variables

```
$Filepath = 'C:\Users\mad tom vane\Documents\Test1.xlsx'
$Filepath = Get-Item -Path $Filepath
$NewFilepath = Join-Path -path $Filepath.directory.fullname -ChildPath "$($Filepath.basename).xls"
```

[Open Excel up](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx)

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true #or false
```

I like to [open in Read-Only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx)

```
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Filepath.fullname,[Type]::Missing,$true)
```

Save the [workbook as xlExcel8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159513/what-is-the-correct-xlfileformat-enumeration-for-excel-97-2003) for [an XLS file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx)

```
$Workbook.SaveAs($NewFilepath,56)

#https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx
$Workbook.Close()
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
Remove-Variable Excel
```

Comment: Any chance this script works on a 2003 server? Im thinking no since it looks like a rename process.

Comment: I've tested this "script" (lines of code) on PowerShell 2.0 and it all works. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: my apologies, i meant will it work on the server if the server does not have excel/office 2007+ ? in other words, does the machine have to have the ability to create .xlsx files natively. the above works well on my 7 and 8.1 machines but i have office 2013 on both of them. the 2003 server only has office 2003.

Comment: Good question. I don't have Office 2003 to test with. I'd just test it and see what errors arise.

Comment: Also use `$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false` to suppress the alert.